# How can I preload videos in a playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

It annoys me how I can't have the next video loading when the current is done buffering. Or can I?

I'm looking for a Chrome extension to be specific but any other mainstream browser's extension would be alright.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for recommendation for a browser extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[**This Chrome extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgdfnbpkmkkdhgidgcpdkgpdlfjcgnnh) automatically stops autoplay at Youtube but keeps on buffering. It's possible to open several tabs without the need to pause each one of them. The greatest drawback is that it will also pause playlists.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I do is, when the current video is done Buffering I open the next video in a new tab; turn down it's volume to zero or pause it and let it buffer.

There is no feature in YouTube to have it done automatically.

Comment: I was hoping for a Chrome extension or any other's browser application actually. I'll edit the question specifying it.